.Net MCV Project is not loading in Visual Studio 2022 community edition
I recently installed Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition on Windows 11 and tried to load a .NET MVC 5 application. However, the project appears as (unloaded) in the solution. When I attempt to reload it, I get an error message stating, "A project with that name is already opened in the solution."
After some research, I discovered that removing the following ProjectTypeGuids from webconfig:
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
I tried removing this section, and while the project does load, it is recognized as a class library rather than a web application.
Even when I try to create a new MVC application, it gives me following error when I click the "Create" button:
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM
Could you please guide me on how to resolve this issue and ensure the project loads correctly as a web application? Thank you!

Which .NET version is the MVC 5 project using? You might need to install additional tools/features via Visual Studio installer to be able to run those.

The project is initially in .NET 4.5 version, but I upgraded to .NET 4.8 upon loading. I’ve installed all the related tools and features, but could you recommend any specific ones that I might help?

@JerdineSabio I already installed related tools/features. Can you be more specific?

Can you share a minimal reproducible example without personal privacy through GitHub?

Maybe you have opened it before in the new desktop, check it.

The ProjectTypeGuids element in your .csproj file specifies what type of project it is.  For example, {349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21} is associated with ASP. NET Web Applications, and {fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc} is for C# projects.
By removing these GUIDs, Visual Studio might no longer recognize the project as a Web Application and may treat it as a class library instead.  This is why, after removing them, your project is loading as a class library instead of a Web Application.
You can resolve the issue of your .NET MVC 5 project showing as "unloaded" in Visual Studio and the error "A project with that name is already opened in the solution" by cleaning and rebuilding the solution, delete the bin and obj folders, repair Visual Studio and update Visual Studio to the latest version and etc.

I already did this multiple times!
